# How to unset array inside array

Tags: php, arrays, array-unset

I have an array in the following structure

```
Array ( [members] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [nr] => 2 [email] => email1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [nr] => 6 [email] => email2 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [nr] => 3 [email] => email3 ) 
 )
 [title] => List members 
)
```

I want to delete items [3] => Array () by nr, like unset [nr] => 3,
so how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop over members items and check if `nr` has the value you want. Then, you could use `unset()` to remove the entry :

```
foreach ($array['members'] as $key => $item) {
    if (isset($item['nr']) && $item['nr'] == 3) {
        unset($array['members'][$key]) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) instead of unset I'd filter the values that you actually need.

```
$array['members'] = array_filter($array['members'], function($member) {
    return $member['nr'] !== 3;
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/03b7a5e9a29d3f369d2caf4e3b3cfacaab6b2a59)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `unset($main['members'][2]['nr']);` if you dont want to use foreach loop